# How get only value from dictionary on Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with two values for each key, but I need separate values to different variables.

Example:

```
key1: (value1, value2)

var1 = value1
var2 = value2
```

How do i do this?

Comment: `var1, var2 = dict_name[key1]`

Comment: What's the context? If you just need it once, then see @Vishal's comment, but if you're looping through the dict, then it would be different, e.g. `for key, (var1, var2) in d.items()`. The answer might also depend on what you're doing with the variables. You can [edit] the question. See [ask] if you want tips.